# How do I load an Enterprise Library Configuration from a string

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I have an Enterprise Library configuration XML serialised and loaded into a String object.

Is there any way to initialise an Enterprise Library logging component with that string?

I am looking for something like this:

```
IConfigurationSource configSource = new SomethingConfigurationSource(stringWhichHasConfig);
LogWriterFactory logFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configSource);
LogWriter writer = logFactory.Create();
```

Is there any way to actually do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was to write the configuration into a temporary file, and load that configuration as follows:

```
string loggingConfigSetting = GetSetting("LoggingConfiguration");

string tempConfigPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.AppendAllText(tempConfigPath, loggingConfigSetting);

FileConfigurationSource configSource = new FileConfigurationSource(tempConfigPath);
LogWriterFactory logFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configSource);
writer = logFactory.Create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize the string into Configuration Object understood by the ent lib.

Comment: Can you please give more details? Which object does the XML deserialise to?